# Where does Eclipse get list up update sites from?

Tags: android, eclipse

Yesterday I installed Eclipse 3.7.2 (Indigo) and I'm trying to configure it.   This is the 32 bit version on a 32 bit Ubuntu system.  When I do a "Check for Updates" it returns the following error:

*'Contacting Software Sites' has encountered a problem.
Unable to read repository at http:/android/eclipse/content.xml.
Host name may not be null*

Note the **single slash** after "http:"

Where does it get this URL from and how do I fix it?   . . . N.B. this URL is **not** in the Available Software Sites section of Install/Update under Preferences.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Help] > [Install New Software...] > [Available Software Sites] and edit the bad url there.

Comment: That's the same list as the one under Preferences, and, as I said above, it's not in that list.